# Convert PDF to EPUB in Python

Tags: python, arabic, aspose.words

I'm trying to use the Aspose-words library in Python to convert a PDF file containing Arabic text to an EPUB file. While the library works perfectly fine with English text, I'm facing some issues with Arabic text. Specifically, the resulting EPUB file seems to have some gibberish characters instead of the original Arabic text.

I'm wondering if there's anything specific I need to do when working with Arabic text using Aspose-words library in Python.

Any advice on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I have tried this code

```
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("arabic.pdf")

doc.save("Output.epub")
```

but didn't get expected result after converting to epub.

Comment: I would recommend you to post your question along with your document in Aspose.Words support forum https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8. Also, please note, Aspose.Words is designed to work with flow MS Word documents. While reading PDF documents, the fixed page PDF document are converted to flow document model. Unfortunately, such conversion does not guaranty 100% fidelity.

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov Thank you for you suggestion. Appreciate it :)